# Red hat linux command line character underscore problem

Tags: command-line

When I type a command e.g.

```
cd /etc/
```

I get the following

```
cd /etc$
```

if I press the backslash key again then I get the correct entry

```
cd /etc/
```

I am using gnome but I get the same problem with KDE.

Does anyone know what may be causing this problem?

Comment: Underscore or dollar sign? Backslash or backspace? Please describe *exactly* the sequence of keys that you type.

Comment: Is the `$` a real character?  What happens if you don't hit the backspace and hit Enter?  Does it send `cd /etc/$` to the prompt, or does it ignore the `$`?

Comment: Note: Please use codetags, to distinguish code from description in prose.

Comment: You write `if I press the backslash key again`, but why do you hit it, and in which way again? Do you confuse slash and backslash here? What do you mean? And: to cd into /etc you don't need a trailing slash.

Comment: And in the headline, you're talking about an `underscore problem`. What do you mean by that?

Comment: We could probably figure this out if we got some more information, but this seems abandoned, so I'm going to close it

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like your shell is severely misinformed about the terminal type you are using.  This is normally communicated to applications through the TERM environment variable, I believe.  I think the usual situation is to have an `export TERM=xterm` or similar in your `.bashrc` or other file that is automatically executed on login or when a shell is spawned.